# Eclipse: Update compare view

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse provides the option to **Compare With > Each Other** for files.

I'd like to refresh the resulting view for two text files in my target folder successively  while developing my application.

<kbd>F5</kbd> does not work.

Comment: Close compare view, refresh, compare again.

Comment: It's a pain that this doesn't work without closing and re-opening the view. In other editors (e.g. WinMerge) the view updates automatically when saving the files after editing. This should happen in Eclipse, too, IHMO.

Comment: Has anyone seen a bug for this? If not, is someone willing to file one?

Answer (score 1):

I have a drop down called JavaScript Source Compare. If I switch between this and Text Compare and back again it does a refresh. This is quicker than closing and reopening. Hope this helps.